# Error when running prophet model via airflow - 'StanModel' object has no attribute 'fit_class'

Tags: python, airflow, facebook-prophet

I have a model that uses the python Prophet library for some predictive analytics.  The code runs fine locally but when I run it via an Airflow DAG, I get the following error:

```
[2022-01-11, 18:47:00 UTC] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - AttributeError: 'StanModel' object has no attribute 'fit_class'
[2022-01-11, 18:47:00 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
```

I have airflow installed via a docker container and have made sure that all Prophet dependencies are the correct versions within the container lib directory (/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages).

I am using prophet 1.0.1 and pystan 2.19.1.1.

Most of the other posts referencing this error state making sure the pystan version is correct to match the Prophet version, which it does.

Any suggestions on what I can look?

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to this issue was ensuring the correct 'user' was being used when new python packages were installed via the requirements.txt file.  While the packages (prophet and pystan) were installing properly and compiling fine, the pip install was done via the 'root' user when it needed to be the 'airflow' user on airflow containers as thats the user where the DAGs run from.